# run a code with each 'continue' statement in a java 'while' loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Let's say we have a java ***while*** loop with a lot of ***continue*** statements in it:

```
while (...)
{
    // code A...
    continue;

    // code B...
    continue;

    // code C...
    continue;

    code D...
}
```

What if we need to run the same code before every `continue`? i.e. code A, B, and C above are all the same. How would you avoid code duplication?

I am trying to avoid code duplication by not having to 'paste' that code before every continue;

Comment: Your skeleton of code, as posted above, might be too vague for anyone to venture an exact answer.  Can you show us the actual code?

Comment: Did you try if statements? I generally avoid continue and try to let the next iteration happen by the natural flow of execution.

Comment: You can shift those code in a function and call that function before continue

Comment: So you are trying to avoid code duplication by not having to write that code before every `continue;`. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Actually I agree with your comments. There are a bunch of 'strategies' imaginable. But I thought there might be smarter ways of doing this that I wasn't aware of. Honestly I hate to 'paste' a line of code all over my code.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, you're exactly right. I edited my question accordingly. Thnx

Comment: If this were me, I'd move the entire content of the loop to another method, and replace each `continue` with `return`.  Maybe your repeated boilerplate could stay in the original loop.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `try...finally` block. Say your original code is like this:

```
while(...) {
    if (condition1) {
        duplicatedCode();
        continue;
    }
    ...
    if (condition2) {
        duplicatedCode();
        continue;
    }
    ...
    if (condition3) {
        duplicatedCode();
        continue;
    }
    otherCode();
}
```

You can reduce the duplication like this:

```
while(...) {
    boolean shouldRun = true;
    try {
        if (condition1) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
        if (condition2) {
            continue;
        }
        ...
        if (condition3) {
            continue;
        }
        otherCode();
        shouldRun = false;
    } finally {
        if (shouldRun)
            duplicatedCode();
    }
}
```

Though I'm not sure if this is better readability-wise...

Comment: I don't think this adds anything to the readability of the code; but I appreciate your collaboration.

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani Well, you can't always have the cake and eat it :( Less code duplication, or more readability? Depends on which one you think is more important. I would go with the latter. Let's wait and see if anyone else comes up with a better solution.

Comment: I guess you're right. Some 'goto' statement would work here; but we know that's not an option in Java

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a continue, you can use a loop statement if the conditions are similar

```
while(...)
{
...
continue;
...
continue;
...
}
```

change it to

```
for(....) {
if(...)
    continue;
if(...)
    continue;
}
```